# Why getting this exception "System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream" inconsistently

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf-binding

I am getting the exception "System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream" whil loading the hotlist data from the web service. Plz find below the exception log trace for the same.

> [2014-12-09 09:38:10.4402]  Information: 0033216: <-Get Hot List
>   Started() [2014-12-09 09:38:33.9415]        Error: 0033217:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this
>   stream.
>
> Server stack trace:     at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.CreateResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebResponse response)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.WebResponseHttpInput.WebResponseInputStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.BufferMessageStream(Stream
>   stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream,
>   BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType) 
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage
>   httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   DMS.Integration.Proxy.Reference.ReferenceWebService.getHotlist(getHotlistRequest
>   request)    at
>   DMS.Integration.Proxy.Reference.ReferenceWebServiceClient.DMS.Integration.Proxy.Reference.ReferenceWebService.getHotlist(getHotlistRequest
>   request)    at
>   DMS.Integration.Proxy.Reference.ReferenceWebServiceClient.getHotlist(getHotlist
>   getHotlist1)    at DMS.Services.HotListServiceProxy.GetHotList()    at
>   DMS.GUI.Utils.AddToHotListHelper.b__5()    at
>   DMS.Lib.Base.ServiceProxyWrapper`1.Execute() [2014-12-09
>   09:38:33.9415]        Error: 0033218: System.ApplicationException:
>   getHotList
>
> [2014-12-09 09:38:33.9415]  Information: 0033219: Service Call Timing,
>   94835ms, Action :getHotList

I can confirm that while getting the hotlist, we are not doing any memory stream operations.

Please find below the bindings for the service in app.config:

```
 <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicBinding" maxBufferSize="209715200" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

The isssue is coming in QA environment and application is installed on server and by connecting to VPN only they can access the application for testing.

Comment: Now I'm curious - was there ever a solution to this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS [Exactly!](https://xkcd.com/979/)